# Is there any way to compare columns in df like this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a df, and I want to compare 1 column to each of the remaining columns in the df, count and calculate the ratio.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

indices = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
col = ["gender", "under 15", "homework finishing"]

data = (["Female", True, "No"], ["Female", False, "Yes"], ["Male", True, "Yes"], ["Female", True, "No"],
       ["Male", True, "No"], ["Female", False, "Yes"])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = indices, columns = col)
```

[image]

And I want the result to be:

[image]

Initially, I tried using multiindex but failed. Or should I use groupby?

I am wondering if it is possible to do this by pandas? Any hint or help is welcome

Comment: sounds like you could use `groupby`. And pretty much anything you can think of with tables is possible in pandas

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure how you want to divide it, since your first column has both `Gender` and `Under 15` as indices, and the values are split into halves between them somehow (it doesn't add up with your first table example either).

But this kind of resembles your example:

```
>>> df.groupby(["gender", "homework finishing"]).size().unstack()

homework finishing  No  Yes
gender                     
Female               2    2
Male                 1    1
>>> df.groupby(["under 15", "homework finishing"]).size().unstack()

homework finishing   No  Yes
under 15                    
False               NaN  2.0
True                3.0  1.0
```

You of course still need to add the percentage division, but I'm sure you can manage that.

Comment: Thank you so much, may I ask if it is possible to make "gender" and "under 15" as a 2-level index?

Comment: you should be able to add the two new tables together

Comment: I tried, but I don't see indices "under15" and "gender" any more. I just see True, False, "Female", "Male"

Comment: I'm not really sure how this will be achieved